# QTableWidget does not displaying properly inside another qwidget

Tags: c++, qt

Why i am getting this result image with result

[image]

instead of something like this image with expecting result

[image]

but inside another QWidget.

Code that i am using:`

```
AxiesConfigurationInterface::AxiesConfigurationInterface(QWidget *Parent) :
        QWidget(Parent)
{
    MainAxiesConfigurationLayout = new QGridLayout;
    AxiesConfigurationTable = new QTableWidget;
    AxiesConfigurationTable->setRowCount(8);
    AxiesConfigurationTable->setColumnCount(5);
    QLabel *Test1 = new QLabel("How are you?");
    QLabel *Test2 = new QLabel("I am fine. What about you?");
    MainAxiesConfigurationLayout->addWidget(Test1);
    MainAxiesConfigurationLayout->addWidget(Test2);
    MainAxiesConfigurationLayout->addWidget(AxiesConfigurationTable);
    setLayout(MainAxiesConfigurationLayout);
}
```

`

Comment: A similar code give me headers with the number ... May be the problem is not in this code but elsewhere. Something strange : with this code, your QtableWidget has to be under the QLabel, and it is not in your image.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do but... `MainAxiesConfigurationLayout->addWidget(Test1)` will effectively call [`QLayout::addWidget(Test1)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addWidget) because you haven't specified a row and/or column for the newly added widget.  Try specifying the placement of the widget explicitly with [`QGridLayout::addWidget(Test1, row, col)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget).

Comment: The problem is not with this two labels but with how qtablewidget is displayed

Comment: I guess that i somehow messed up stuff below this qwidget.